# If we have some Binary Search Tree and perform the operations add(x) followed by remove(x) do we necessarily return to the original tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

The value of x should be the same. Do we get the same tree back again with one add and one remove operation?

Comment: It depends on how the `add` and `remove` operations are defined as well as whether BSTs are permitted to contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not necessarily. The set of elements does not uniquely determine the structure of the tree, and there are many ways to implement a BST, with different mechanisms for adding and removing elements. Some types of BST, such as self-balancing BSTs, can adjust themselves in ways that destroy information about their previous structures, and therefore these operations are not generally reversible.

For instance, suppose we have a self-balancing BST:

```
  8
 / \
3   9
 \
  4
```

We add 5:

```
    8
   / \
  4   9
 / \
3   5
```

and remove 5:

```
    8
   / \
  4   9
 /
3
```

Comment: Can you please explain about an AVL tree too? That will be really helpful.

Comment: @Abdullahnaeem: What about it? The tree in my answer could be an AVL tree.